# Create a fast filter with a custom function on a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, cython, scikit-image

I would like to implement a filter on numpy array which compute locally (given a footprint) **the average distance to the central pixel**.
This function is similar to the local standard deviation, but takes the center pixel as the reference instead of the average.

One part of the problem is that my arrays are **multimodal** 2d images (rgb for example).

I have a full numpy implementation, that uses indexing tricks to perform the task, but it is limited to a 3x3 neighborhood for technical reasons.

I was thinking implementing this in cython, following [this](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/6342ec594fb48126013305155d5643a3d9764557/skimage/filters/rank/generic_cy.pyx) for example, but it seems not to work for vector images (with more than one value per pixel).

A numpy implementation (kind of pseudo code!) would look something like this:

```
img: np.ndarray  # source image of shape (n, m, 3) for example
mask: np.ndarray  # mask representing valid data (n, m)
footprint = disk(5)
n_px_nh = footprint.sum()
out = np.zeros(img.shape)
for i, neighborhood, masked_px in local_2d_filter(img, footprint, mask):
    # going through
    center_px = neighborhood[n_px_nh/2]  # works if n_px_nh is odd of course
    center_diff = 0
    for px in neighborhood[masked_px]:
        center_diff += ((px - center_px) ** 2).sum() ** 0.5  # distance to the center pixel
    center_diff /= n_px_nh
    out[i] = center_diff
```

`local_2d_filter` would be a function, like scipy.ndimage.generic_filter, which goes through an image, returning pixels in the footprint, around the center pixel .

Has anyone an idea on how to implement such filter ?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is still vague, you should at least include a small example (10x10 or 15x15 image).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added to the post a pseudocode of what the function would be implemented !

Comment: Using Cython seems to be a good idea, but "*it seems not to work for vector images*" is not very precise. What about providing the Cython code having the issue? Did you take care to cast values so not to get any overflow in the Cytohn implementation?

Comment: I was meaning that you can give a custom function to scipy.ndimage.generic_filter, but it does not handle vector images, only 2d or 3d images with scalar pixels. I'm trying to do the full implementation in cython now

Comment: ```the average distance to the central pixel```... What you are referring to sounds like the **median absolute deviation** or **MAD**.  Maybe you've already searched for solutions under that term, but if you haven't it might help.

Comment: Hmm, I was hopeful for a second, but by central pixel I mean the center of the neighborhood, nothing to do with the median I guess... Still interesting to hear about MAD, I didn't know about that, thanks !